# Evaluate C(21,2) using Pascal's Identity??

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Looking over a practice exam for my midterm on Friday...I came across the following question:

Evaluate C(21,2) using Pascal's Identity.

I have written down in my notes that Pascals identity means that C(n,k) + C(n,k-1) = C(n+1,k) for 1 <= k <= n+1 & for any natural number.
Example: C(4,2) + C(4,3) = C(5,3)

How might I go about using this to evaluate something? I don't understand what the question is asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using you notations:

$$C(21,2)= C(20,1) + C(20,2) \\
= C(20,1) + C(19,1) + C(19,2) \\
= C(20,1) + C(19,1) + C(18,1) + C(18,2) 
$$
now go on until
$$ C(21,2)=C(20,1) + C(19,1) + C(18,1) + \ldots + C(2,1)+ C(2,2)$$
Now, $C(k,1) = k $ and $C(k,k) =1 $ so 
$$ C(21,2)=20+19+18+ \ldots + 2+1 = \frac{20\times 21}2 = 210$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on where the 20 x 21 / 2 comes from?? I don't understand how you got that from 20+19+18...+2+1

Comment: Nevermind, just realized that if you lay 1+2+3....+20 underneath, each pair adds up to 21.  21*20 / 2 = sum

Comment: [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)

Answer (score 0):

Apply Pascal's Identity repeatedly and you will notice that

$${21\choose2} = {20\choose1}+{19\choose1}+{18\choose1}+\cdots+{2\choose1}+{2\choose2}$$

$$20+19+18+\cdots+2+1 = \frac{20*21}{2} = 210$$

On the other hand$$ {21\choose2} = \frac{21!}{19!.2!} = 210$$.  That is it!!

Comment: Thanks a bunch, however the above answer broke it down a bit more and was easier to understand.

Comment: We were just a minute apart and Mookid is really good in LATEX.

Comment: No explanation needed, I would've accepted your answer if he didn't submit his... What is LATEX? the code to create the pictures for 21 choose 2 = 20 choose 1...etc??? I have to learn that myself.

Comment: Latex is the code that you choose to write down mathematical expressions.  Welcome to MSE!!